# Conditional in Rails partial depending on the context page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering if I could execute / display some stuff differently in partials depending on the context in which it appears.

For example, I have a _user_info partial that appears in a sidebar, and also in the user page, and I want to display some extra info in the second case. How can I express that kind of conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is something this:

```
if params[:controller].eql?('users')
  view code
```

However I would split the partial into two separate partials and display the distinct parts from whichever view you need.

Comment: Great, so I could just filter by controller or / and action, right?

Comment: Yes, you could condition however you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `controller_name` and `action_name` methods.

```
if controller_name == 'user' && action_name == 'show'
  details
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it just depends on how you want to discover/expose that context. The simple way is conditionals, which can be set in any number of ways, or derived from a set of conditions. That can happen in a filter, an action, etc.

If the changes are large enough, better to just encapsulate them in separate partials.

Another option is to wrap the `render` tag in a helper that calculates/grabs those conditions.

It kind of depends on the nature of the conditions, where/how you want to deal with them, etc.

Comment: They are very small changes, like displaying the user avatar in a larger size for the user page, so I believe that for this case it's better to adhere to DRY and not creating and maintaining two separate partials...  So I would just call my user avatar method with different parameters, what do you think would be the best option?

Comment: Some tiny changes are better off inline (IMO). Some people abstract *all* that kind of stuff into helpers; I think there's a point of diminishing returns, but I see their point. Once they're not tiny, it definitely makes sense to turn them into helpers, or additional partials. Where you draw that line is often just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Or pass a variable into the partial via :locals =>