# Conditional link display in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a filter bar on my page. The bar should always be in place, however only when I'm on the detail page I want to show a link <- back to list inside of it. Otherwise the filter bar should be empty. What is the most elegant way of doing this in rails 3 or 3.1?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Could you add the relevant code for that? Do you have pages for e.g. `index` and `show` and a partial for the filter bar? When you show your concrete code (only the relevant parts), the answer will be concrete.

Comment: OK, let me try to elaborate a little more. Since I want to have the filter bar in place on every page, I've put it into the application.html.erb. It looks like this:
<section id="filter-bar">
    <section id="filter"></section>
  </section>
Now, on the detail page the filter should contain a link back and on the homepage just nothing or something else. I'd prefer not to use any display: none kind of tricks. So what is the in rails way for achieving this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return to previous page you can use `link_to "Back", :back`

To show or hide the link you can use the `controller_name` and `action_name` methods with a `if/unless` conditional.

Comment: I know Fernando, I'm asking how to display the link only on the detail page and hide on other pages.

Comment: Sound good, can you please elaborate on the second sentence. I'm new to rails. I'd appreciate if you could point me to an article or the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Examples to show/hide are [in this another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455215/conditional-in-rails-partial-depending-on-the-context-page/7466351#7466351)

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks! Where do I have to put this code? Into a helper?

Answer (score 0):

From your question and the comment, you have the following structure:

```
application.html.erb:
...
<section id="filter-bar"> 
  <section id="filter"></section> 
</section>
```

I see there two different options how to include your link conditionally:

1. By doing an `if-then` in your file  `application.html.erb`
2. By including a `yield` with a symbol that denotes the context.

Here is the pseudo-code for that:

1. solution

   ```
   application.html.erb:
   ...
   <section id="filter-bar"> 
     <section id="filter">
       <% if controller_name == 'user' && action_name == 'show' %>
         <%= link_to "Back", :index %>
       <% end %>
     </section> 
   </section>
   ```
2. solution

   ```
   application.html.erb:
   ...
   <section id="filter-bar"> 
     <section id="filter">
       <%= yield(:filter) %>
     </section> 
   </section>

   view.html.erb:
   <%- content_for :filter do %>
     <%= link_to "Back", :index %>
   <% end %>
   ...

   index.html.erb:
   // No content_for section in the file, so it will be empty here.
   ```

The first solution is simpler, much more condensed, but all the information if something is included or not is in one file. If that is changed a lot, that may be a hotspot in your application. The second is more object-oriented, but perhaps more to change and think about. But both will working for you.